# Program not returning string

Tags: java

For an online java course, I'm coding the Caesar Cipher. Here, you input a string and a shift number, and the answer returns with the shifted string, where all the characters are shifted "down" the alphabet by the shift number. For my program, I also have a grouping exercise, where I have to group the shifted string into groups of a certain number (ex: "SGHSJDGDKGHSA" grouped by 3 is "SGH SJD GDK GHSA"). If the number of characters in the string is not divisible by the grouping number, then the program adds lowercase x's to the end of the string (ex: "SGHSJDGDKGHSA" grouped by 4 is "SGHS JDGD KGHS Axxx").

My program works until the grouping function (the groupify method in my code). The string with the groups is not returned. Any advice on how to fix this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Crypto {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a phrase.");
        String userText = input.nextLine();
        String normText = normalizeText(userText);

        System.out.println("Enter a shift.");
        String strUserShift = input.nextLine();
        int userShift = Integer.parseInt(strUserShift);
        String shiftText = shiftAlphabet(userShift, normText);
        System.out.println("Shifted Text: " + shiftText);

        System.out.println("Enter a grouping number.");
        String strUserGroupNum = input.nextLine();
        int userGroupNum = Integer.parseInt(strUserGroupNum);
        String encryptedText = groupify(shiftText, userGroupNum);
        System.out.print(encryptedText);

    }

    private static String normalizeText(String preText) {
        StringBuilder newText = new StringBuilder();
        for(int charNum = 0; charNum < preText.length(); charNum++) {
            char charText = preText.charAt(charNum);
            if (charText == '.' || charText == ',' || charText == ':' || charText == ';' || charText == '\'' || charText == '\\' || charText == '"' || charText == '!' || charText == '?' || charText == '(' || charText == ')') {
                newText.append("");
            } else {
                String stringText = "" + charText;
                stringText = stringText.toUpperCase();
                newText.append(stringText);
            }
        }
        return(newText.toString());
    }

    private static String shiftAlphabet(int shift, String normText) {
        StringBuilder shiftedText = new StringBuilder();
        String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toUpperCase();
        for (int index = 0; index < normText.length(); index++) {
            char currentChar = normText.charAt(index);
            int currentCharNum = alphabet.indexOf(currentChar);

            int newCharNum = currentCharNum + shift;

            while (newCharNum >= 26 || newCharNum < 0) {
                if (newCharNum >= 26) {
                    newCharNum -= 26;
                } else {
                    newCharNum += 26;
                }
            }

            char newChar = alphabet.charAt(newCharNum);
            shiftedText.append(newChar);
        }
        return(shiftedText.toString());
    }

    private static String groupify(String shiftText, int groupNum) {
        StringBuilder sbShiftText = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbGroupText = new StringBuilder();
        String finalText = "";

        while (sbShiftText.length() % groupNum != 0) {
            sbShiftText.append("x");
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= sbShiftText.length(); i++) {
            if (groupNum == 1) {
                finalText = shiftText;
            } else {
                // everything w group number > 1
                if (groupNum % i == 0) {
                    sbGroupText.append(" ");
                } else {
                    String tempStr = sbShiftText.charAt(i) + "";
                    sbGroupText.append(tempStr);
                }
                finalText = sbGroupText.toString();
            }
        }
        return(finalText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working solution slightly modified https://repl.it/@omurbekjk/DesertedDistinctLight:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a phrase.");
        String userText = input.nextLine();
        String normText = normalizeText(userText);

        System.out.println("Enter a shift.");
        String strUserShift = input.nextLine();
        int userShift = Integer.parseInt(strUserShift);
        String shiftText = shiftAlphabet(userShift, normText);
        System.out.println("Shifted Text: " + shiftText);

        System.out.println("Enter a grouping number.");
        String strUserGroupNum = input.nextLine();
        int userGroupNum = Integer.parseInt(strUserGroupNum);
        String encryptedText = groupify(shiftText, userGroupNum);
        System.out.print(encryptedText);

    }

    private static String normalizeText(String preText) {
        StringBuilder newText = new StringBuilder();
        for(int charNum = 0; charNum < preText.length(); charNum++) {
            char charText = preText.charAt(charNum);
            if (charText == '.' || charText == ',' || charText == ':' || charText == ';' || charText == '\'' || charText == '\\' || charText == '"' || charText == '!' || charText == '?' || charText == '(' || charText == ')') {
                newText.append("");
            } else {
                String stringText = "" + charText;
                stringText = stringText.toUpperCase();
                newText.append(stringText);
            }
        }
        return(newText.toString());
    }

    private static String shiftAlphabet(int shift, String normText) {
        StringBuilder shiftedText = new StringBuilder();
        String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toUpperCase();
        for (int index = 0; index < normText.length(); index++) {
            char currentChar = normText.charAt(index);
            int currentCharNum = alphabet.indexOf(currentChar);

            int newCharNum = currentCharNum + shift;

            while (newCharNum >= 26 || newCharNum < 0) {
                if (newCharNum >= 26) {
                    newCharNum -= 26;
                } else {
                    newCharNum += 26;
                }
            }

            char newChar = alphabet.charAt(newCharNum);
            shiftedText.append(newChar);
        }
        return(shiftedText.toString());
    }

    private static String groupify(String shiftText, int groupNum) {
        StringBuilder sbShiftText = new StringBuilder(shiftText);
        StringBuilder sbGroupText = new StringBuilder();
        String finalText = "";
        String temp = "";
        int remainder = sbShiftText.length() % groupNum; 
        while (remainder>0) {
            sbShiftText.append("x");
            remainder--;
        }
        int grouping = 0;
        System.out.println(sbShiftText);
        System.out.println(groupNum);
        for (int i = 0; i < sbShiftText.length(); i++) {
            temp += sbShiftText.charAt(i);
            grouping++;
            if (groupNum == grouping) {
                finalText += temp + " ";
                temp="";
                grouping=0;
            } 
        }
        return(finalText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sbShiftText` is defined but never initialised, hence `sbShiftText.length()` is not valid.

It should be like this:
`StringBuilder sbShiftText = new StringBuilder(shiftText);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to debug the groupify() method. And if dont know how to debug it then learn it.

Problem in groupify() method is when you declaring this

```
StringBuilder sbShiftText = new StringBuilder();
```

the sbShiftText is empty, so sbShiftText.length() returns 0. Therefore your while loop and for loop are not running at all.

First initialize sbShiftText with shiftText like

```
StringBuilder sbShiftText = new StringBuilder(shiftText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String groupify(String shiftText, int groupNum) {
        StringBuilder sbShiftText = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbGroupText = new StringBuilder();
        String finalText = "";

        *sbShiftText.append(shiftText);*
        while (sbShiftText.length() % groupNum != 0) {
            sbShiftText.append("x");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <sbShiftText.length(); i++) {
            if (groupNum == 1) {
                finalText = shiftText;
            } 
            else {
                if (*i%groupNum* == 0&&i!=0) {
                    sbGroupText.append(" ");
                } 
                String tempStr = sbShiftText.charAt(i) + "";
                sbGroupText.append(tempStr);
                finalText = sbGroupText.toString();
            }
        }
        return finalText;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share some explanation about your code such that others can learn from it?